# how can I change the name of an image in cloudinary from the api

Tags: cloudinary

For example I have this image:

```
http://res.cloudinary.com/xxxx/image/upload/v1520903853/tt/aa/ee/E14/name_2018-03-12_19_17_31.jpg
```

I need rename to:

```
myname.jpg
```

and move to the route:

```
/tt/aa/
```

how can do it? I am using javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to rename an image, you can use our API. However, because it is signed (for security reason) you will need to use server-side script. For example in NodeJS:

cloudinary.v2.uploader.rename(from_public_id, to_public_id, options, callback);

In your case:

cloudinary.v2.uploader.rename("tt/aa/ee/E14/name_2018-03-12_19_17_31", "/tt/aa/myname", options, callback);

Please note, in order to bypass the CDN caching, you can include the invalidate parameter in your POST

You can read more about it here:
https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#rename

Comment: is imposible do it using jquery for example?

Comment: in client-side?